# blueimp / jQuery-File-Upload Thumbnails not working

Tags: jquery, file-upload, blueimp

I just installed [jQuery-File-Upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) and I was testing demo on my raspberry pi (apache2), upload works but there is error message `Failed to create scaled version: thumbnail` I didn't change anything in files so where is the problem?

I also tested same demo on XAMPP and there was working fine

Answer (score 0):

Install GD Library on Raspbery pi

```
sudo apt-get install php5-gd
```

then it works :)